# Pokemon Reborn first gym?

Tags: pokemon-reborn

What is the easiest way to beat the first gym in Pokemon Reborn?
I eventually got through it by some luck and sheer save bashing, but was there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

[Dustox](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dustox_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) proved helpful for this fight.

It is also helpful to learn how to anticipate the use of explosion, so you an switch out a weaker Pokémon, to take the hit. This way, your main Pokémon will not be instantly knocked out.

Comment: How do you get a dustox at that level? Dustox is a second evolution, isn't it? Where can you obtain a Wurmple?

Comment: Also, how does one "anticipate" the use of a move? I haven't looked in depth into the RNG of reborn, but I'd assume moves are chosen mostly randomly.

Answer (score -2):

Hi the easiest way to get through the first gym is,
Try to get water starter pokemon like Squirtle or Piplup.
When you battle Brock, use water type moves like Water Gun/Hydro Pump.

I did find a useful [guide](https://pkmnreborn.com/forums/viewthread.php?id=100) and the [fandom](https://pkmnreborn.fandom.com/wiki/Best_way_to_train), refer it might help you climb levels faster.

Comment: Bad answer for several reasons. 1. We're not talking about the same game. 2. "Just choose a different starter" is never good advice in a Pokemon game. 3. "Just use type advantage" is usually not helpful either.

Comment: By choose a different starter, I meant try different type pokemon preferably 'Water' type as the first gym is has rock type pokemons. Also, moves like Water Gun, Surf, Hydro pump, Toxic and Fly could be beneficial.

Comment: Again, we're not talking about the same game. The first gym in Reborn is electric type, not rock.

Answer (score -3):

Here are some strategies:

- See what moves they know by having a muck up battle.
- Type advantage: see what types the gym uses
- Use tough Pokemon with high speed, attack, defense and HP.

Comment: have you actually played reborn before?